# Any benefit buying 2 barrels?

Tags: gwent

At the Shop, there is an option to buy 2 barrels.

Are there any benefits for that, like, an extra special card or better quality cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shop offers several packages of kegs at different prices.

The first option allows you to buy 1 or more kegs for 100 Ore each. When you click this package, you get to select a number of kegs to purchase.

The other options allow you to buy a specific number of kegs for real money. The more kegs you buy at once, the cheaper each keg is, so buying larger packages offers a discount, while smaller packages cost less in total.

Other than the real money discount for buying larger amounts of kegs at once, there is no difference between the kegs, regardless of how you obtained them.